# Facebook messenger - Broadcast message_creative_id is reusable or not?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Is there any way to reuse message template (message_creative_id) to send broadcast message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only one time we can use message_creative_id. one id for one broadcast